# reshape wide to long using prefix as id in R

Tags: r, reshape

In R, Is it possible to use the reshape function to reshape a data-frame from wide to long with keeping the prefix of the name as the id and the suffix as the column names?

For example, I might have a long data-frame like this:

```
log_a_mean | b_mean | c_mean | log_a_std | b_std | c_std | log_a_N | b_N | c_N
_______________________________________________________________________________

 1         |  2     |   3    |    4      |   5   |   6   |   7     |  8  | 9
```

And I want it to be reshaped to:

```
id    | mean  | std   | N
_____________________________
log_a |  1    | 4     | 7
  b   |  2    | 5     | 8
  c   |  3    | 6     | 9
```

Comment: I'm guessing you're attracting downvotes because these `reshape` questions have been asked probably 100's of times on this site previously under the `r` tag. I'd be astounded if you couldn't find your answer quite quickly through Google or a Stackoverflow site search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what I had to do in my current project.
I use `reshape2` in conjonction with `data.table`.
That last package is not necessary but I am used to it and wrote the code for it (doesn't change things much though).

What you need to do first is some string manipulation in order to isolate the id from the real variable. The rule we'll apply will be that the variable from the input table has the form `<id>_<variable>`. id can have an underscore but variable can't. Basically, we'll look for the last underscore and cut from there. Then, you just cast the whole thing.

This will be our dataset :

```
d=data.table(
    log_a_mean=1,
    b_mean=2,
    c_mean=3,
    log_a_std=4,
    b_std=5,
    c_std=6,
    log_a_N=7,
    b_N=8,
    c_N=9)
```

First, we melt it :

```
d=melt(d,variable.factor=FALSE)
```

The output looks like :

```
variable    value
log_a_mean     1
b_mean         2
... etc.
```

Now we split the variable :

```
splitvar=function(v){
as.data.frame(
  t(sapply(
    strsplit(v,"_",fixed=TRUE),
    function(x) c(paste(x[1:(length(x)-1)],collapse="_"),x[length(x)])
  )),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}

d[,c("id","variable"):=splitvar(variable)]
```

The output of `d` now looks like

```
variable value id
mean         1 log_a
mean         2 b
... etc.
```

Casting it :

```
d=dcast.data.table(d,id~variable)
```

Output of `d` is now :

```
   id N mean std
    b 8    2   5
    c 9    3   6
log_a 7    1   4
```

I suggest you complete a bit your question so you don't get downvoted that fast. It is an interesting one as it is a problem I stumble on a couple of times so it has its uses for everyone. However, it is hard to find interest in the question the way you formatted it.

Answer (score 1):

Using the devel version of `data.table` i.e. [`v1.9.5`](http://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table), this could be done easily. You can install it by following [these instructions](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

This new feature in `melt.data.table` allows melting to multiple columns by providing the column indices to be joined, separately, as a list to `measure.vars` argument.

Using `d` from @YacineH's post:

```
library(data.table)
# Get prefix of column names
nm1 <- unique(sub('_[^_]+$', '', names(d)))

d.m <- melt(d, measure.vars = list(1:3, 4:6, 7:9), 
              variable.name="id", value.name=c("mean", "std", "N"))
setattr(d.m$id, 'levels', nm1)
#      id mean std N
#1: log_a    1   4 7
#2:     b    2   5 8
#3:     c    3   6 9
```

Since `variable` column by default returns a factor column with numbers from 1 to `length(measure.vars)` when it is a list, we simply replace the levels with `nm1` after melting.

---

Alternatively, you can use `reshape` from `base R`

```
#convert the 'data.table' to 'data.frame (if needed)
setDF(d)
#specify direction as 'long' and the column index in a list
#change the 'id' values to 'nm1' and rearrange the columns
d1 <- transform(reshape(d, direction='long', 
           varying=list(1:3, 4:6, 7:9))[-1], id=nm1)[c(4,1:3)]
#remove the prefix of column names
colnames(d1) <- sub('.*_', '', colnames(d1) )
row.names(d1) <- NULL
d1
#      id mean std N
#1 log_a    1   4 7
#2     b    2   5 8
#3     c    3   6 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `merged.stack` from my "splitstackshape" package. It requires a unique ID per row, which I've just added as the `1:nrow(dt)`.

The approach would be (using "d" from @YacineH's answer):

```
library(splitstackshape)
merged.stack(d[, id := 1:nrow(d)],                ## Add the id if it doesn't exist
             var.stubs = c("mean", "std", "N"),   ## Specify the stubs
             sep = "var.stubs",                   ## The sep is just the stubs 
             atStart = FALSE)                     ## The stubs are not at the start
#    id .time_1 mean std N
# 1:  1      b_    2   5 8
# 2:  1      c_    3   6 9
# 3:  1  log_a_    1   4 7
```

Use a basic `gsub` to remove the trailing "`_`" (`[, .time_1 := gsub("_$", "", .time_1)][]`)and you're done.