# R, pivoting wide to long with extracting prefixes. In tidy way

Tags: r, tidyverse

I think I'm doing something almost exactly like this question: [reshape wide to long using prefix as id in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28800472/reshape-wide-to-long-using-prefix-as-id-in-r)

But I'd love to use the tidyverse if possible.

I have this data.  The columns are two sets of nearly identical variables with either a "pre" or "post" in front of it.

```
data<-structure(list(PreConfidence_NonMarginal = c(3, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 
5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4), PreConfidenceMarginal = c(1, 
1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1), PreConfidenceInstruments = c(3, 
2, 2, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3), PreConfidenceSutures = c(2, 
1, 2, 4, 2, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3), PreFamiliarAnatomy = c(3, 
3, 2, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3), PreEfficient = c(1, 
1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 3), PostConfidence_NonMarginal = c(4, 
3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4), PostConfidenceMarginal = c(2, 
2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3), PostConfidenceInstruments = c(3, 
3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 3), PostConfidenceSutures = c(3, 
3, 4, 4, 3, 5, 3, 5, 5, 4, 5, 3, 3, 3, 5, 4, 3, 3), PostFamiliarAnatomy = c(3, 
4, 2, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4), PostEfficient = c(2, 
2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 
-18L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And I'd love to pivot longer so that the columns are "pre" and "post" with the rest of the variable name as the new row title.  Ideally the result would look like something like this:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

We may use `pivot_longer` with `names_pattern` - capturing the prefix part (`Pre` or `Post`) and the rest (`.*)` of the characters while specifying the `names_to` as a vector of `".value"` - value of the columns and the suffix part of the column name in 'Question' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = everything(), 
   names_to = c(".value", "Question"), names_pattern = "(Pre|Post)(.*)")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 108 × 3
   Question                 Pre  Post
   <chr>                  <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Confidence_NonMarginal     3     4
 2 ConfidenceMarginal         1     2
 3 ConfidenceInstruments      3     3
 4 ConfidenceSutures          2     3
 5 FamiliarAnatomy            3     3
 6 Efficient                  1     2
 7 Confidence_NonMarginal     1     3
 8 ConfidenceMarginal         1     2
 9 ConfidenceInstruments      2     3
10 ConfidenceSutures          1     3
# … with 98 more rows
```